# How to use capistrano v3 and shared config files with ERB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, config, capistrano3

I'm converting my RoR app to use capistrano v3. I have a number of configuration file that are generated by ERB. Most of these files, like like /etc/logrotate.d/app_name, are referenced external to my app. So I like the idea of linking them to my shared/config directory. Capistrano supports managing linked files via the linked_files array. So far so good. But, the files to be linked don't technically exist until I run ERB. And capistrano runs :deploy:check:linked_files as the first step of :starting, at which point the files don't exist and the check fails.

So my question is, what's a really good way to handle this? Do I check in empty config files in my config directory, let capistrano link them to shared, and then overwrite them via ERB at a later stage? That doesn't feel good. I can't generate them before the :starting task because on an initial deploy the source tree isn't there yet. Any suggestions?